# Simplification of vector cross product

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

If I have

$-\mathbf{N}_u = a\mathbf{x_u} + b\mathbf{x_v}$

$-\mathbf{N}_v = c\mathbf{x_u} + d\mathbf{x_v}$

Then, why is $\mathbf{x_u} \times \mathbf{N_v} + \mathbf{N_u} \times \mathbf{x_v} = -(a+d)\mathbf{x_u} \times \mathbf{x_v}$?

Admittedly, my cross product algebra is pretty rusty but I just can't see why $-c \mathbf{x_u} \times \mathbf{x_u} - b \mathbf{x_v} \times \mathbf{x_v}=0$

Comment: Just look at the definition. $z \times z = 0$. The rest is just multiplication.

Comment: The rustiness of my cross products is clear. Thank you very much

Comment: It's entirely overkill here, but suppose we take a dot product of the LHS with $\mathbf{x}_\mathbf{u}$. Since the four vectors defined in this problem are coplanar, the resulting pair of triple products vanish. Thus the LHS must be orthogonal to $\mathbf{x}_\mathbf{u}$, and the same logic applies for $\mathbf{x}_\mathbf{v}$. The only way for this to happen is for the LHS to be proportional to the cross product, as indeed it is.